# How can I enforce a rule where only one instance of a class can have a certain parameter set to true?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

In my .Net Core Entity Framework game, I have a relationship between the Castle and CastleKnights classes.

The Castle can have many CastleKnights associcated with one Castle.

But each Castle can only have one CastleKnight that is flagged as the imposter(IsImposter).

I'm trying to figure out how I can ensure that each Castle only has one CastleKnight that has the IsImposter flag set to `true`.

I tried this , putting this in my CastleKnights class, but it did not work:

```
if(IsImposter = true) {

}
```

It tells me that `the name "IsImposter" does not exist in the current context`.

How can I get the Casetle class to "know" when a Castle already has a CastleKnight with `IsImposter` set to true?

Thanks!

Here are my 2 classes:

```
 public partial class Castle
{
    public Castle()
    {
        CastleKnights = new HashSet<CastleKnights>();
    }
    [Key]
    public Guid CastleId { get; set; }
    public string CastleDescription { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CastleKnights> CastleKnights { get; set; }
}


public partial class CastleKnights
{
    public Guid KnightId { get; set; }
    public Guid? CastleId { get; set; }
    public bool? IsImposter { get; set; }

    public virtual Castle Castle { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps place a `public CatleKnights KnightImposter` property/column directly on `Castle`

Comment: @Charlieface oh ok thanks, so if there is no `imposter` yet, then that would be null?  and if the there is, that value would be the `CastleKnight` that has `IsImposter` set to true?

Comment: I wouldn't have an `IsImposter` at all. Keep the data all in one place, either on the one or the other

Comment: @Charlieface Im sorry, I misunderstood.  Ok, So remove `public bool? IsImposter { get; set; }` from my CastleKnights class.  Then just have `public CatleKnights KnightImposter` in my Castle class?  But if I did that, how would I check to see if I already have an Imposter, or if a knight was an imposter?  Thank you so much

Comment: Can a CastleKnight be an imposter in multiple Castles? If not then you need a separate table CastleKnightImposter which is FK on CastleKnight and contains Imposters. The `KnightImposter` is FK on that.

Comment: @Charlieface Hi!  No each CastleKnight is bound to one Castle(CastleId) only.  So a Knight can only be in one castle and can only be an imposter in one castle.  That is determined by the CastleId.   Thank friend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that placing a new readonly property on your Castle Class such as:

```cs
    public partial class Castle
    {
        ...

        public bool HasImposter
        {
            get
            {
                return CastleKnights.Where(knight => knight.IsImposter == true).SingleOrDefault() != null;
            }
        }
    }
```

And enforcing that whenever later in your code you create a new Knight instance, obliged yourself to provide some value for **IsImpostor** property

```cs
    public partial class CastleKnights
    {
        public CastleKnights(bool isImposter)
        {
            IsImposter = isImposter;
        }
        
        public bool IsImposter { get; private set; }
        ...
    }
```

Read more about Linq "Single" method [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-element-operator-single-singleordefault)

Comment: Thanks, so would I use `IsImposter = isImposter;` as a check everytime I load the game and on each CastleKnight?

Comment: Sorry buddy I didn't follow you, the ```IsImposter = isImposter;``` part I suggested you because whenever you instantiate a new CastelKnight i.e ```var knight = new CastleKnights()``` you'll need to provide some value for the property IsImpostor i.e: ```var knight = new CastleKnights(isImpostor: false);``` hence, keeping track in code when you fire up the logic of the impostor and erase the posibility of ```null``` values, because now IsImposter property is mandatory

Comment: Oh hi, thanks! that makes sense!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since you only ever need to track one imposter per castle, consider tracking them as a property in the `Castle` class:

```
 public partial class Castle
{
    public Castle()
    {
        CastleKnights = new HashSet<CastleKnights>();
    }
    [Key]
    public Guid CastleId { get; set; }
    public string CastleDescription { get; set; }
    public CastleKnights ImpostorKnight;

    public virtual ICollection<CastleKnights> CastleKnights { get; set; }
}
```

...then, just point to whichever instance of `CastleKnights` is the impostor.

Comment: Thanks! But how would I check that in the future?  Like so if I needed to check to see my Castle had an imposter or if I was adding a new knight to the castle, I'd need to check to see if there was an imposter so I don't accidently try setting a 2nd imposter causing a big error... thank you!